# ¿Es posible guardar el contenido de un panel en un archivo binario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, bitmap

En relacion a mi pregunta ¿Es posible guardar el contenido de un panel en un archivo binario?

Lo que necesito es saber si es posible y cómo podría desarrollarlo. Es decir tengo un panel sobre el cual puedo dibujar. Luego de dibujar me gustaría poder guardar lo que se dibujó en un archivo binario, que luego otro programa podrá montarlo y leerlo.

Esto es en C# winform

Guarda el panel pero no el contenido del Panel (pnl_Draw) :

```
 //Incializa un componente SaveFileDialog.
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    //Cuando buscas archivos te muestra todos los .bmp.
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
            //Titulo
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar gráfico como imagen";
        // preguntamos si elegiste un nombre de archivo.
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Extención del archivo por defecto segun el filtro del saveFileDialog
            switch (saveFileDialog.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "jpg";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "bmp";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "gif";
                    break;
            }

            //Obtenemos alto y ancho del panel
            int width = pnl_Draw.Width;
            int height = pnl_Draw.Height;
            //Inicializamos un objeto BitMap con las dimensiones del Panel
            Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            //Inicializamos un objeto Rectangle en la posicion 0,0 y con dimensiones iguales a las del panel.
            //0,0 y las mismas dimensiones del panel porque queremos tomar todo el panel
            // o si solo queremos tomar una parte pues podemos dar un punto de inicio diferente y dimensiones distintas.
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            //Este metodo hace la magia de copiar las graficas a el objeto Bitmap
            pnl_Draw.DrawToBitmap(bitMap, rec);
            // Y por ultimo salvamos el archivo pasando como parametro el nombre que asignamos en el saveDialogFile
            bitMap.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Gracias a [Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) pude ver que estaba utilizando el metodo equivocado. Para guardar el contenido se debe dibujar [con Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint)

Comment: como es que estas dibujando? usas GDI sobre un control Panel

Comment: Estoy usando using System.Drawing

Comment: El dibujo no puedes hacerlo alli mismo, para eso se usa el evento Paint https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint  Es alli donde tienes que dibujar y la operacion de grabar obtienes lo que en el Paint creaste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias recuperar la imagen del control usando DrawToBitmap()

[Control.DrawToBitmap Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)

Una vez que tengas la imagen puedes grabar a un archvo con el metodo Save()

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Panel1.ClientRectangle.Width, Panel1.ClientRectangle.Height);
Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp,new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height));

bmp.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

[Saving image to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909905/saving-image-to-file)

Comment: Sí es lo que hago para cuando quiero guardar la imagen que dibujo en el panel. Lo que sucede es que no sé, Cómo serializarlo.

Soy bastante novato, lo que quiero aprender es a poder:
-Guardar lo que dibujo en el panel.
- Guardar el archivo serializado.

Comment: como serializarlo? una imagen de por si ya es un archivo binario, no se tiene que serializar nada, el bitmap es la serializacion de la imagen dentro del panel

Comment: Abría alguna forma de que se pueda guardar los valores que dibujo, es decir contar los puntos verdes, y su x,y (así con los otros colores)

Comment: Para guardar el archivo uso este metodo.

SaveFileDialog
Bitmap

Comment: Si la imagen la construyes mediante codigo a medida que uses los componentes de GDI podrias en paralelo definir una estructura de clases que refleje esa misma operacion. O sea si dibujas un cuadrado en tal posicion con tanto de lado, podrias crear una clase Rectangulo con propiedades que defina esa misma informacion. Cuando terminas el dibujo podrias serializar esa estructura ya sea a xml o a binario. No se si eso es a donde apuntas?

Comment: Exacto para eso mismo, entonces voy a corregir lo de Paint, y luego crear una estructura de clases que refleje lo que se dibuja, para luego  serializar la estructura!

Cuando este por serializar si tengo alguna duda, haré una pregunta nueva. MUCHAS GRACIAS!! Leandro siempre SUPER activo andas!

Comment: Para serializar el objeto usa los componentes de .net https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx